# How to fix this Response code:422, Response message:Unprocessable Entity while using post method in jmeter?

Tags: api, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

When I try to perform the post method from jmeter .it will show [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILBF7.png). how to resolve this issue? my request body and URL are correct and it's also working in postman.[response body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xiQ9.png) please help me to resolve this issue.

I try to load testing for my project. get method is working fine in my jmeter but the post method is not working it will show an error message like Response code:422
Response message:Unprocessable Entity error.

how to fix this error?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of text.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: That error does not come from jmeter - it is the response from whatever api you are talking to. You need to look at what the api is expecting, and then find the difference to whatever post body you are sending in this test.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you need to add a [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/http-header-manager) and configure it to send [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) header with the value of [`application/json`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Common_types)

[image]

Otherwise you will need to check your request body and whether it matches your [API contract](https://apievangelist.com/2019/07/15/what-is-an-api-contract/), i.e. the server complains that you didn't provide `productId`